# Storing text in SQL with formatting (breaklines etc.)

Tags: c#, sql, forms, text-formatting

I currently have

```
<textarea id="Commentary" rows="5" cols="40" runat="server"></textarea>
```

Then in the event

```
insertCommand.Parameters["@Commentary"].Value = "<pre>" + Commentary.Value + "</pre>";
```

If I entered into the HTML input box, for example

- new line 1
- new line 2
- New line 3

It puts that into the SQL field as

```
 - new line 1  - new line 2  - new line 3
```

How do I keep things like line breaks? I will be displaying the data in a table, so I want to keep things such as line breaks.

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not changes formatting. All required symbols are there. But if you are looking at it in MS Sql Server Management studio it won't show you formatting.  At the same time you should be able to select it from database later and put on your page. And formatting will be kept.

Comment: Thanks. I can put it back in a form and it will display with linebreaks, however when I read and put into a GridView it doesn't.

Comment: Question is how you put it in GridView. Possibly you do it in a way that formatting is removed by GridView. Try to put database request result of that Commentary field into ASP:Panel Text property. I see <pre> saved into database - it should work nice.

Comment: Thanks, I guess as it wasn't displaying in SSMS nor the GridView I thought it was a problem with my saving the text and the pre tags was wrong. I will mark this as answer and assume it was right all along and its my gridview that needs changing. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Besides this, you may also run into html encoding issues.
So you may wanna check the `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` class.
Though this does not encode whitespace, you can do a simple String.Replace on top of the encoding like this:

```
HttpUtility.HtmlEncode(Commentary.Value).Replace("\n", "<br/>")
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this code

```
var reader = new StringReader(Commentary.Text);

string line;
while(null != (line = reader.ReadLine()) 
{
 ...
}
```